# Is it possible to redirect stdout and stderr in a Visual Studio 2022 native unit test?

Tags: unit-testing, c++14, stdout, visual-studio-2022

I have a large C++ library that I want to run under the VS2022 native unit test framework in order to analyse code coverage for a few test cases.

The library writes to stdout and stderr and both the library and my test method also launches child processes (using CreateProcess()) which also write to stdout and stderr.

I would like to capture the stdout and stderr from the library and the child processes.

I have tried to redirect stdout, stderr (and stdin) by various techniques including the one shown below.

I call RedirectStdoutAndStdinToFile() on entry to a test method (passing in method sepcific file names)  and restoreSTDIO() before returning from the method. The code below works intermittently but I get two problems:

1. sometimes I get nothing more than the first write of a test message to my output files and
2. sometimes it throws the following exception:

```
Invalid parameter detected in function _isatty, minkernel\crts\ucrt\src\appcrt\lowio\isatty.cpp line 17. Expression: (fh >= 0 && (unsigned)fh < (unsigned)_nhandle)
```

The exception seems to only be thrown :

- during execution of my cleanup method but not at the same point in that method each time I run the test.
- when not single stepping through the code with the debugger.

I read elsewhere the it was necessary to redirect stdin as well as stdout and stderr because of the way that VS2022 uses a console but the redirection of stdin below has not resolved the problem.

Should it be possible to get this to work?

```
class stdioRedirection
{

    FILE* oldStdout ;
    FILE* oldStdin ;
    FILE* newoutFile ;
    FILE* newinFile ;
    FILE* oldStderr ;
    FILE* newErrFile ;

<etc>
}

void stdioRedirection::RedirectStdoutAndStdinToFile(const char* outFilename, const char* errFilename, const char* inFilename)
{
    // Save the current stdout and stdin streams
    oldStdout = stdout;
    oldStdin = stdin;
    oldStderr = stderr;
    newoutFile = stdout;
    newinFile = stdin;
    newErrFile = stderr;

    // Open the output file in write mode and redirect stdout to it
    errno_t r = freopen_s(&newoutFile, outFilename, "w", stdout);
    if (r != 0)
    {
        throw CustomException((char*)"redirectSTDIO freopen of stdout failed");
    }

    // Open the input file in read mode and redirect stdin to it
    r  = freopen_s(&newinFile, inFilename, "r", stdin);
    if (r != 0)
    {
        throw CustomException((char*)"redirectSTDIO freopen of stdin failed");
    }

    r = freopen_s(&newErrFile, errFilename, "w", stderr);
    if (r != 0)
    {
        throw CustomException((char*)"redirectSTDIO freopen of stderr failed");
    }


    if (newoutFile != nullptr && newinFile != nullptr && newErrFile != nullptr)
    {
  
        std::cout << "test message";
        std::cerr << "test message";

    }
    else
    {
        throw CustomException((char*)"redirectSTDIO freopen failed");

    }
}

void stdioRedirection::restoreSTDIO()
{
    FILE* temp;
    // Restore stdout and stdin by redirecting them back to the original streams
    int r = freopen_s(&temp, "CON", "w", oldStdout);
    r += freopen_s(&temp, "CON", "r", oldStdin);
    r += freopen_s(&temp, "CON", "w", oldStderr);
    if (r != 0)
    {
       throw CustomException((char*)"retore failed");
    }
    // Close the output and input files if necessary
    fclose(newoutFile);
    fclose(newinFile);
    fclose(newErrFile);
}
```

Comment: I am surprised that I have had no responses to this question. I'm wondering whether that is because it is an unusual problem that no-one else has hit or whether the question needs clarification.  I would really like to know whether I should continue to puzzle over this problem or give up. Advice welcome.